# What does this mean? : note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const account&’

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the errors that we generally face in out C++ programs.

While compiling a program I got a error (I did this error intentionally, please don't tell that how to correct that) and there a note is present which is :

```
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const account&’
```

I want to understand the meaning of this note.

My program is :

```
#include<iostream>
class account
{
    private:
        int a_no;
    public:
        account()
        {
            a_no = 0;
        }
        void showData()
        {
            std::cout<<"\n account number = "<<a_no<<std::endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    account a1;
    a1.showData();
    account a2(2);
    a2.showData();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that I haven't defined a constructor which can take one argument and doing that will remove my error.

Okay, while compiling this I got:

```
file1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
file1.cpp:20:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘account::account(int)’
     account a2(2);
                 ^
file1.cpp:20:17: note: candidates are:
file1.cpp:7:9: note: account::account()
         account()
         ^
file1.cpp:7:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
file1.cpp:2:7: note: account::account(const account&)
 class account
       ^
file1.cpp:2:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const account&’
```

I want to know what is meaning of last line `file1.cpp:2:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const account&’` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You already know that you don't have an constructor that takes an int.
2) You know that you are trying to construct account with an int.
3) If you don't do it, compilers will create default copy-constructors, assignment-operators
4) The default copy-constructor takes a const reference to account

So what happens here? As there is only a default-constructor and you are constructing with one parameter the compiler thinks you want to copy-construct. As you are giving him an int as parameter for the copy-constructor, the compiler tries to convert the int to an account - which doesn't work, and he tells you about it: "no conversion possible from int to account"

This is very important to know as this is a source of many bugs. You propably didn't want to call the copy-constructor. But what happens if the compiler really finds a way to convert the type you used as a parameter to account? A mess....

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what is meaning of last line file1.cpp:2:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const account&’ ?

First, the message tell you

> no matching function for call to ‘account::account(int)’

And there're two candidates, the 1st is the default ctor, but

> file1.cpp:7:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

The 2nd is the copy ctor (implicitly generated), and its parameter's type is `const account&`, but

> file1.cpp:2:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const account&’

Answer (score 0):

class constructor is a simple function as like as others, so when you send a int type to the function as parameter, you need to define parameter type for function :

```
class account
{
    private:
        int a_no;
    public:
        account(int a){ a_no = a; }     
};
```

now, when you type `account a2(2);` int type defined for constructor and there isn't any problem

Comment: This is probably not the thing which I asked for.

Comment: yes, it was my problem and which has been solved now through other answers to this question :P